# Problem with new lines in cells while reading an Open Document Spreadsheet (*.ods) file in a PHP array with OpenTBS

Tags: php, spreadsheet, ods, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I am trying to read an Open Document Spreadsheet (*.ods) file in PHP using '[TinyButStrong template engine](https://github.com/Skrol29/tinybutstrong)' along with the '[OpenTBS](https://github.com/webonyx/OpenTBS)' plugin. My target is to convert the spreadsheet's cell data into a PHP array.

Sample ods row data (row #4 of *inferno.ods*):

[image]

Here is my code:

```php
include_once('lib/plugins/tbs_3140/tbs_class.php');
include_once('lib/plugins/tbs_3140/opentbs-master/tbs_plugin_opentbs.php');

$TBS = new clsTinyButStrong;
$TBS->Plugin(TBS_INSTALL, OPENTBS_PLUGIN);

$TBS->LoadTemplate('inferno.ods', OPENTBS_ALREADY_UTF8);
$options= array('noerr'=>true);
$metaOdsObj= $TBS->Plugin(OPENTBS_GET_CELLS, '$A:$B', $options);
//$xml = $TBS->Source;

var_dump($metaOdsObj);
//var_dump($xml);
```

The output:

```
array(6) {
...
[3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(5)
    [1]=>
    string(4) "THE "
  }
...
}
```

Note that only the first line of the cell data (separated by a new line) is fetched as the cell value. How can I get the complete text (with new lines) of a cell as an array value? Any clues?

`$TBS->Source` fetches the contents in XML with each line inside the cells separated by a `<text:p>` tag. I tried using PHP *SimpleXML* and *DOMDocument::loadXML* with this xml data without the desired outcome.

Thank you for reading this far. And also a ton of thanks for giving it a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an OpenTBS bug that limits the string cell reading to the first line.

This bug is fixed as of OpenTBS 1.11.0-beta4.
You can patch the function *OpenDoc_GetCellValue()* using the code available at GitHub.

Thanks for reporting this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt action.